# specifying ur5 robot_description in moveit_commander.RobotCommander() initialization

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to specify the robot_description parameter in initializing the moveit_commander for my robot. As [in the documentation](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ff50476c4070eb86d0a70aa39281d5805db13fa5/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/move_group.py#L51) the moveit_commander takes a robot_description, which I expect is a URDF file. Below is how I am attempting to do so:

```
desc = '/home/team-sewts/catkin_ws/src/fmauch_universal_robot/ur_description/urdf'
klaus_commander = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description = desc, ns = "klaus")
frank_commander = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description = desc, ns = "frank")
scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()


group_name = "manipulator" #manipulator in gazebo
klaus_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name, desc, "klaus")
frank_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name, desc, "frank")
```

However I am getting an error reading `[ERROR] [1575984235.264155297]: Robot model parameter not found! Did you remap '/home/team-sewts/catkin_ws/src/fmauch_universal_robot/ur_description/urdf'?`. I am guessing that I am not specifying the urdf correctly - how can I do so for my moveit_commander? Full error output below, please let me know if anything else is needed.

```
team-sewts@sewts-Legion:~/catkin_ws/src/moveit_scripts$ python x2_coordinate_tester.py
Failed to import pyassimp, see https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/86 for more info
[ERROR] [1575984235.264155297]: Robot model parameter not found! Did you remap '/home/team-sewts/catkin_ws/src/fmauch_universal_robot/ur_description/urdf'?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x2_coordinate_tester.py", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "x2_coordinate_tester.py", line 266, in main
    tutorial = MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial()
  File "x2_coordinate_tester.py", line 30, in __init__
    klaus_commander = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description = desc, ns = "klaus")
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/robot.py", line 151, in __init__
    self._r = _moveit_robot_interface.RobotInterface(robot_description, ns)
RuntimeError: RobotInterfacePython: invalid robot model 


team-sewts@sewts-Legion:~/catkin_ws/src/moveit_scripts$ python coordinate_tester.py
Failed to import pyassimp, see https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/86 for more info
[ERROR] [1576058021.474502119]: Robot model parameter not found! Did you remap '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from /home/team-sewts/catkin_ws/src/fmauch_universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/ur5_joint_limited_robot.urdf.xacro | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="ur5" xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so" name="ros_control">
      <!--robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace-->
<!--robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType-->
    </plugin>
    <!--
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_power_monitor_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_power_monitor.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>1.0</updateRate>
      <timeout>5</timeout>
      <powerStateTopic>power_state</powerStateTopic>
      <powerStateRate>10.0</powerStateRate>
<fullChargeCapacity>87.78</fullChargeCapacity>
      <dischargeRate>-474</dischargeRate>
      <chargeRate>525</chargeRate>
      <dischargeVoltage>15.52</dischargeVoltage>
      <chargeVoltage>16.41</chargeVoltage>
    </plugin>
-->
  </gazebo>
  <!-- measured from model -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 3.14159265359" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/base.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 3.14159265359" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/base.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="4.0"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00443333156" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00443333156" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0072"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="shoulder_pan_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="shoulder_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 3.14168042022" xyz="0 0 0.0893072092318"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="150.0" lower="-3.14159265359" upper="3.14159265359" velocity="3.15"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="shoulder_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 3.14159265359" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/shoulder.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 3.14159265359" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/shoulder.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="3.7"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0149723523444" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0149723523444" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01040625"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="shoulder_lift_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="shoulder_link"/>
    <child link="upper_arm_link"/>
    <origin rpy="1.57027963108 0 -0.000256378975585" xyz="8.02597230883e-05 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="150.0" lower="-3.14159265359" upper="3.14159265359" velocity="3.15"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="upper_arm_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 -1.57079632679" xyz="0 0 0.136"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/upperarm.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 -1.57079632679" xyz="0 0 0.136"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/upperarm.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="8.393"/>
      <origin rpy="0 1.57079632679 0" xyz="-0.212658283841 0.0 0.136"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.134074052685" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.134074052685" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0151074"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="elbow_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="upper_arm_link"/>
    <child link="forearm_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0.000150389826896 0.000670340723934 -0.000129296667033" xyz="-0.425316567681 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="150.0" lower="-3.14159265359" upper="3.14159265359" velocity="3.15"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="forearm_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 -1.57079632679" xyz="0 0 0.0165"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/forearm.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 -1.57079632679" xyz="0 0 0.0165"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/forearm.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="2.275"/>
      <origin rpy="0 1.57079632679 0" xyz="-0.212658283841 0.0 0.0165"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0312142241249" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0312142241249" iyz="0.0" izz="0.004095"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="wrist_1_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="forearm_link"/>
    <child link="wrist_1_link"/>
    <origin rpy="3.13404114506 3.139985598 3.14149191057" xyz="-0.392232740578 0.000835269385168 0.110607503694"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="28.0" lower="-3.14159265359" upper="3.14159265359" velocity="3.2"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="wrist_1_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.093"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/wrist1.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.093"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/wrist1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.219"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00263096286494" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00263096286494" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0034284375"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="wrist_2_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="wrist_1_link"/>
    <child link="wrist_2_link"/>
    <origin rpy="1.57084155987 0 5.57612237128e-05" xyz="3.88210393792e-05 -0.0949976987238 -4.2970377454e-06"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="28.0" lower="-3.14159265359" upper="3.14159265359" velocity="3.2"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="wrist_2_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.095"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/wrist2.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.095"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/wrist2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.219"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00179418220221" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00179418220221" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0021942"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="wrist_3_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="wrist_2_link"/>
    <child link="wrist_3_link"/>
    <origin rpy="1.57047457779 3.14159265359 -3.14148013852" xyz="7.18408705395e-05 0.0828382643859 -2.66531297376e-05"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="28.0" lower="-3.14159265359" upper="3.14159265359" velocity="3.2"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="wrist_3_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.0818"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/wrist3.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.57079632679 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.0823"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/wrist3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1879"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.01525"/>
      <inertia ixx="8.06247260834e-05" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="8.06247260834e-05" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0001321171875"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="ee_fixed_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="wrist_3_link"/>
    <child link="ee_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 -1.57079632679 1.57079632679" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="ee_link">
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.01 0 0"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="wrist_3_passive_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="wrist_3_link"/>
    <child link="tool0"/>
  </joint>
  <transmission name="shoulder_pan_trans">
<type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="shoulder_pan_joint">
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="shoulder_pan_motor">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="shoulder_lift_trans">
<type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="shoulder_lift_joint">
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="shoulder_lift_motor">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="elbow_trans">
<type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="elbow_joint">
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="elbow_motor">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="wrist_1_trans">
<type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wrist_1_joint">
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="wrist_1_motor">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="wrist_2_trans">
<type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wrist_2_joint">
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="wrist_2_motor">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="wrist_3_trans">
<type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wrist_3_joint">
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="wrist_3_motor">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <gazebo reference="shoulder_link">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="upper_arm_link">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="forearm_link">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="wrist_1_link">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="wrist_3_link">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="wrist_2_link">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="ee_link">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- ROS base_link to UR 'Base' Coordinates transform -->
  <link name="base"/>
  <joint name="base_link-base_fixed_joint" type="fixed">
    <!-- NOTE: this rotation is only needed as long as base_link itself is
                 not corrected wrt the real robot (ie: rotated over 180
                 degrees)
      -->
    <origin rpy="0 0 -3.14159265359" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- Frame coincident with all-zeros TCP on UR controller -->
  <link name="tool0"/>
  <link name="world"/>
  <joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>
</robot>

'?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coordinate_tester.py", line 272, in <module>
    main()
  File "coordinate_tester.py", line 250, in main
    tutorial = MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial()
  File "coordinate_tester.py", line 42, in __init__
    robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/robot.py", line 151, in __init__
    self._r = _moveit_robot_interface.RobotInterface(robot_description, ns)
RuntimeError: RobotInterfacePython: invalid robot model
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339604/specifying-ur5-robot_description-in-moveit_commander.robotcommander()-initialization/) by [shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49514/shu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2019-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `robot_description` parameter actually should be set to the *name* of the parameter that contains your robot description.

It's not a file path, but the name of the parameter itself.

By default, that would be `robot_description` (hence the default value there being `robot_description`).

You'll have to load the actual contents of the file in `/home/team-sewts/catkin_ws/src/fmauch_universal_robot/ur_description/urdf` into a parameter and then pass the name of that parameter to the `RobotCommander` constructor.

But perhaps you could (re)use one of the `*_upload.launch` files provided with the `ur_description` package, as it already does all of that for you.

Be sure to select the correct one (ie: the one that matches the robot you're trying to use.

---

Edit: just to be clear: I'm referrig to *ROS parameters* there, not the concept of parameters and arguments to functions and constructors as you find in generic programming languages.

You seem to be loading the *contents* of a urdf file into a Python variable and then passing that as an argument to the `RobotCommander` constructor. That is not what you should do.

You only need to pass *the name* of the *ROS parameter*. No contents.

---

Edit 2:

> Does `ur5_upload.launch` pass the urdf file into a ros parameter that `robot_description` is set to?

Yes and no.

Yes: it does load the file into a parameter.

No: it does not load the file into "a ros parameter that `robot_description` is set to". The `.launch` file loads it into a parameter that is actually called `robot_description`. Please note the difference.

The `.launch` file is stand-alone, it does not know anything about the `RobotCommander`.

I wouls also recommend to not use any different name for the parameter, as `robot_description` is standard and unless you have a very good reason, should not be changed.

> Typing `rosparam get /robot_description` (I think that's the same parameter as robot_description, let me know if I'm wrong) returns the whole urdf file.

That is indeed the parameter.

You don't have to interact with it at all actually: just `roslaunch` the `.launch` file and start your Python script. Things should just work without specifying any custom name for the `robot_description` parameter. Your use is not special. The default values should work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49514/shu/) on 2019-12-11**:
Thanks for explaining. Does `ur5_upload.launch` pass the urdf file into a ros parameter that `robot_description` is set to? I'm having a look at the file and I'm having trouble understanding how the urdf is passed into robot_description.

Typing `rosparam get /robot_description` (I think that's the same parameter as robot_description, let me know if I'm wrong) returns the whole urdf file.

edit:

No: it does not load the file into "a ros parameter that robot_description is set to". The .launch file loads it into a parameter that is actually called robot_description. Please note the difference.

So does this mean there are two robot_description parameters? One that the Commander takes during initialization and one that `ur5_upload.launch` passes the urdf file into?

**Comment by [shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49514/shu/) on 2019-12-11**:
Since I'm specifying namespaces for the robots the script will not run unless I specify a `robot_description`. I am finding that running

```
klaus_commander = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description = '/klaus/robot_description', ns = "klaus")
frank_commander = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description = '/frank/robot_description', ns = "frank")
```

is at least running, but I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to do as I'm having a different issue which I don't know is caused by specifying the `robot_description` (all commands are being sent to one robot).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-11**:
Yes, you'd have to take namespaces into account. But I'm surprised `RobotCommander` does not look in the namespace you're giving it the `ns` argument.

re: commands: `robot_description` is purely used for the robot model (ie: kinematics and visualisation). It's not involved in actuation.